# parsing dependency version requirement specification in python

Tags: python, regex, maven, package

Is there a more efficient way to parse dependency version requirement specification referenced here and extract the version in python. (https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependency_Version_Requirement_Specification)

This is what I've got so far and it feels not the most efficient way. and I guess it's buggy.

```
for version in versions:
    pattern = re.findall("\(,[.0-9]+|[.0-9]+\)|[.0-9]+|\([.0-9]+", version)
    if pattern:
        for matches in pattern:
            if ([match for match in re.findall("[.0-9]+\)", matches)]):
                # this is the less pattern
                pattern_version = "<" + str(matches.decode('utf8')[:-1])
            elif ([match for match in re.findall("\(,[.0-9]+", matches)]):
                pattern_version = ">" + str(matches.decode('utf8')[2:])
            elif ([match for match in re.findall("\([.0-9]+", matches)]):
                pattern_version = ">" + str(matches.decode('utf8')[1:])
            else:
                pattern_version = str(matches.decode('utf8'))
```

expected output would be:

(,1.0],[1.2,) parse to: x <= 1.0 or x >= 1.2

Comment: So you like to extract this information from the pom file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?P<eq>^[\d.]+$)|(?:^\[(?P<heq>[\d.]+)\]$)|(?:(?P<or>(?<=\]|\)),(?=\[|\())|,|(?:(?<=,)(?:(?P<lte>[\d.]+)\]|(?P<lt>[\d.]+)\)))|(?:(?:\[(?P<gte>[\d.]+)|\((?P<gt>[\d.]+))(?=,)))+
```

**Regex will proceed to match version in this order:**

1. First try to match "Soft" requirement using:
   `(?P<eq>^[\d.]+$)`
2. Then try to match "Hard" requirement using:
   `(?:^\[(?P<heq>[\d.]+)\]$)`
3. Otherwise try to match ranges in this order:

   1. First determine if this is a multiple set using:
      `(?:(?P<or>(?<=\]|\)),(?=\[|\())`
      which will only match the comma separating sets.
   2. Then try to match the comma separating ranges within the same set using:
      `,`.
   3. Then proceeds to match the actual ranges:

      1. start matching the upper bound value using
         `(?:(?<=,)(?:(?P<lte>[\d.]+)\]|(?P<lt>[\d.]+)\)))`
      2. then the lower bound value using
         `(?:(?:\[(?P<gte>[\d.]+)|\((?P<gt>[\d.]+))(?=,))`

The result of versions included in the specification will be:

```
| version       | eq  | heq | gte | gt  | or | lte | lt  |
| ------------- | --- | --- | --- | --- | -- | --- | --- |
| 1.0           | 1.0 |     |     |     |    |     |     |
| [1.0]         |     | 1.0 |     |     |    |     |     |
| (,1.0]        |     |     |     |     |    | 1.0 |     |
| [1.2,1.3]     |     |     | 1.2 |     |    | 1.3 |     |
| [1.0,2.0)     |     |     | 1.0 |     |    |     | 2.0 |
| [1.5,)        |     |     | 1.5 |     |    |     |     |
| (,1.0],[1.2,) |     |     | 1.2 |     | ,  | 1.0 |     |
| (,1.1),(1.1,) |     |     |     | 1.1 | ,  |     | 1.1 |
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Aboalnaga, this is exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: happy to be of assistance